# WP_QUERY with alternating post types and pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, sql

I want to show both regular posts and a custom post type (`event`) on the homepage in a single loop. The `event` post type needs to be ordered by a custom field for the event date and show future events. I can easily do this using a `meta_query`. Since setting using a `meta_query` on a query with my events and regular posts won't return the regular posts (since they have no event date) I have used the solution in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129270/81652) to apply the meta query only to the events.

The problem is - since the events are sorted by a future date and the posts are sorted by a past date, the result is all the events followed by all the posts. What I would like to do is alternate the order with a post from each post type - so the result should be: `Event1 - Post1 - Event2 - Post2 - Event3...`

I also need pagination to work as expected.

One solution I can think of is to run 2 separate queries and then alternate displaying a post from each, but I'm not sure how I could reliably get pagination working with that. I could feed the resulting post IDs from 2 separate queries in to a third query but 3 queries doesn't sound like an ideal solution!

I'm assuming this could be done with the SQL from my current code but SQL gives me a headache and I don't know where to start!

Comment: Something like [@birgire's post injector](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141612/31545) might be useful here

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen that looks like exactly what I need (apparently I upvoted the answer so I must have seen it before, not that I remember). I havn't got time now, but as long as I can get it working ok with pagination that will be perfect.

Comment: My pleasure, be sure to update your post if you have any issues, otherwise you can simply post your own answer or mark your post as duplicate. Good luck on your project ;-)

Comment: birgie's injector class did the trick perfectly (with the addition of a meta_query) so I've CV'd as a duplicate. Thanks for the help @PieterGoosen